# Avoid click on same items of Navigation drawer concurrently one after other for fragments and for activities

Tags: android

I am using common Navigation drawer for all activities and fragments but when I am clicking on same item of Navigation drawer also it inflating the same screen. What I want is the same item should not be loaded for second time.

This is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainFragmentsActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}
```

Comment: show your `DrawerItemClickedListener`. How did you code?

Comment: below is my code

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {Intent i = new Intent(MainFragmentsActivity.this,
                        ProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);}

Answer (score 0):

You should not use common navigation drawer for all activities and fragments. Common design pattern is showing different fragments on the main activity for the navigation drawer menu items. And if the user navigates inside any fragment you should open an activity without any navigation drawer but with a back arrow in action bar.

Now if you dont want to show the same fragment then in
onNavigationItemSelected you can write the logic like below -

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG");
      if (fragment == null) 
       {
         Create and attach new fragment
       }else{
          //Do not do anything.
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing, store clicked view'd id to a variable and compare if its the same,

```
int id; // use this variable to store id of clicked view.
@Override public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

     if(id != item.getItemId) {

        id = item.getItemId(); // store clicked id in variable
        // Do your clicking stuffs here...
        if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
           Intent i = new Intent(MainFragmentsActivity.this,   ProfileActivity.class);
           startActivity(i);
           drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For fragments:

if (id == R.id.nav_things_to_do) {
            if (id == R.id.nav_things_to_do && viewPager.getCurrentItem() != 0) {
                Intent main1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainFragmentsActivity.class);
                main1.putExtra("position", 0);
                main1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                main1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                main1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                finish();
                startActivity(main1);
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
            else {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        }
if (id == R.id.nav_all_tasks) {
            if (id == R.id.nav_all_tasks && viewPager.getCurrentItem() != 1) {
                Intent main2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainFragmentsActivity.class);
                main2.putExtra("position", 1);
                main2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                main2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                main2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                finish();
                startActivity(main2);
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
            else {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        }

For Activities:

if (id == R.id.nav_images) {
            try {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainFragmentsActivity.this,
                        SelectFilesActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```